# encoding="utf-8" not working when loading data with spanish characters using a command

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pandas, parsing

Don't know why, but a Django Command gont create a bluk of entries after reading a CSV file. The command does not work locally or when hosted on Heroku.

I'm using pandas library to read the CSV data, but also using encode('utf-8').

At first it worked, but I had to make some changes to the original file and after saving it and making:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

I'm getting error when running the command:

```
python manage.py ubigeo_peru
```

> I've solved this by importing the file as an Excel file, but still
>   wondering what is wrong with the CSV.

```
tmp_data=pd.ExcelFile("static/data/ubigeo-peru.xlsx")

tmp_data=tmp_data.parse("ubigeo-peru")
```

I also see that the encoding error only appear on github when viewing RAW Data:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OmarGonD/stickers_gallito/master/static/data/ubigeo-peru.csv

[image]

**ubigeo_peru.py**

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from shop.models import Peru
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand



tmp_data=pd.read_csv('static/data/ubigeo-peru.csv',sep=',', encoding="utf-8")

# tmp_data=pd.read_csv('static/data/ubigeo-peru.csv',sep=',')

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, **options):
        products = [
            Peru(
                departamento=row['departamento'],
                provincia=row['provincia'],
                distrito=row['distrito'],
                costo_despacho_con_recojo=row['costo_despacho_con_recojo'],
                costo_despacho_sin_recojo=row['costo_despacho_sin_recojo'],
                dias_despacho = row['dias_despacho']

        )
            for idx, row in tmp_data.iterrows()
        ]

        Peru.objects.bulk_create(products)
```

The data looks good on github and when is opened on excel.

```
https://github.com/OmarGonD/stickers_gallito/blob/master/static/data/ubigeo-peru.csv
```

**Error when running the command locally or remotly:**

```
$ python manage.py ubigeo_peru
D:\virtual_envs\stickers-gallito-app\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py:91: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.25.3) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1134, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1240, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1256, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1494, in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 0: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 19, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\stickers-gallito-app\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\virtual_envs\stickers-gallito-app\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\stickers-gallito-app\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 224, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\stickers-gallito-app\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 36, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "C:\Users\OGONZALES\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\web_proyects\stickers-gallito-app\shop\management\commands\ubigeo_peru.py", line 8, in <module>
    tmp_data=pd.read_csv('static/data/ubigeo-peru.csv',sep=',', encoding="utf-8")
  File "D:\virtual_envs\stickers-gallito-app\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\stickers-gallito-app\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 446, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\stickers-gallito-app\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1036, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\stickers-gallito-app\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1848, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 876, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 891, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 968, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1094, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1141, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1240, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1256, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1494, in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 0: invalid start byte
(stickers-gallito-app)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your commit comment, your latest edit was to "correct the encoding" of that file. However, what you did was to change the coding to a single-byte encoding, perhaps Windows CP 1252 (or ISO 8859-1/15, all of which are pretty similar). The file is not UTF-8, so you are lying to Pandas when you tell it that it is:

```
tmp_data=pd.read_csv('static/data/ubigeo-peru.csv',sep=',', encoding="utf-8")
```

Excel will cheerfully handle Windows CP 1252, and apparently whatever Github uses to render CSV files will do that as well. But Pandas goes by the encoding you tell it to use. In short, the fact that a file renders correctly in a browser or application does not mean that the original file was in the encoding you think it is in.

The particular error is generated when Pandas' CSV reader hits the first line for Áncash, because the Á character is 0xC1 in Western European single-byte encodings, and as the error message says 0xC1 is one of the handful of values which cannot appear in a UTF-8 file. The fact that it chokes at that point means that it didn't notice the incorrect encoding of, for example, ó in Asunción, which probably means that it has inserted an replacement character or possibly misinterpreted the input.

In any event, you should either restore the file to the UTF-8 version, or give Pandas the correct encoding when you read it.

Comment: ty. I'll this link to how to save a CSV from Excel with utf-8 encoding as a recordatory.